# HockeyApp UWP doens't log anymore

Tags: uwp, hockeyapp

In December I updated the Nuget to newest version. Since then it stopped logging.

I configure it still the same with this line:

```
        HockeyClient.Current.Configure(ServiceConstants.HOCKEY_APP_WINDOWS_ID);
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

I tested the latest release of the UWP SDK and crash reports were logged as expected. If the suggestions below do not resolve your issue, you can contact HockeyApp directly at https://support.hockeyapp.net

Few things to check:

- That indeed the App ID is correct and there is no whitespace in the string.
- Internet(Client) Capability is checked in your package.appxmanifest
- Default.rd.xml contains the following section in Directives/Application node: `<Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />`

Comment: As far as I know I have all this point fullfilled. But then I will write the support.